# Copy file from sub-folder to parent folder and rename the file with parent folder name

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have the below 5 folders on the desktop.

[image]

Each of these folders has a sub-folder word and the word sub-folder contains file document.xml. For example, This is the path of the file

```
(C:\Users\u0119342\Desktop\LEG_DOWNLOAD\BACK UP DOCX\document\Australian Citizenship (Transitionals and Consequentials) Act 2007\word\document.xml).
```

I would like to move the document.xml out of the sub-folder word to the parent folder `"Australian Citizenship (Transitionals and Consequentials) Act 2007"` and rename it as `"Australian Citizenship (Transitionals and Consequentials) Act 2007"`.

I want to do the same process for all the document.xml files in the rest of the four folders.

Please advise me if there is a way to do this with power shell or batch script.

Thanks,

Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do your job. Give it a try.

```
$Root = "C:\Users\u0119342\Desktop\LEG_DOWNLOAD\BACK UP DOCX\document" 

$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Root

Foreach($Fld in $Folders)
{
    If(Test-Path "$($Fld.FullName)\word\document.xml")
    {
        # Move the file document.xml and rename it
        Move-Item -Path "$($Fld.FullName)\word\document.xml" -Destination "$($Fld.FullName)\$($Fld.Name).xml"

        #Deletes Word folder
        Remove-Item "$($Fld.FullName)\word"
    }
}
```